# Circumference and Piece Length of the Da Vinci Bridge

Tags: geometry, classical-mechanics

Cheers guys,
I want to build a [Da Vinci Bridge](https://www.core77.com/posts/65043/Leonardo-da-Vincis-Ingenious-Design-for-a-Self-Supporting-Bridge) as a rose arch. I want to plant it on two pillars, that are ***d*** units apart. Problem is, I need to figure out the length of each individual wood piece ***l***, so that the whole bridge spans this given distance of ***d***. I know the bridge would approximate a circle, but each piece of wood overhangs a freely choosable distance of ***s***. It rests on another piece of wood with a given thickness ***b***.
I tried to go over the angle ***phi*** that each piece of wood would form in dependence of ***b***, but I can't get there.

I know this is an unusual question, but since I've thought about it for quite some time now, I really want to know the answer for the answers sake itself. I honestly feel it should not be that hard, I just can't really see the "trick".

A badly drawn sketch of the problem:

[image]

Every help is appreciated!

Comment: Old chinese rainbow bridge construction     https://woodenbridgeplans.com/home.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a five-piece bridge, then the third piece must be horizontal and angle $\phi$ must then be half the angle formed by the first piece with ground ($\phi=20°$ in figure below).

The horizontal distance from the left point of the first piece to the midpoint of the third one must be $d/2$, leading to the equation (I took $s$ as the distance from the vertex of angle $\phi$ to the end of the piece, I'm not sure that is what you intended):
$$
(l-s)\cos2\phi+(l-2s)\cos\phi+{l-2s\over2}={d\over2}.
$$

You also ask for the relation between $\phi$ and $b$: if $b$ is the side of the square inscribed in an isosceles triangle with base $l-2s$ and base angles $\phi$, then it is not difficult to see that
$$
\tan\phi={2b\over{l}-2s-b}.
$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it like this general arrangement of Chinese Rainbow Bridge? without overhang $s$? Sometimes  circular wooden logs are filled into the small triangles. Possible to design as intersection of two displaced regular polygons.

[woodenbridgeplans.com/home.html](http://woodenbridgeplans.com/home.html)

[image: Chinese Rainbow Bridge]

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. The advantage of having overhang is that you wouldn't need to fixate the pieces, the whole bridge would hold itself together. The link you provided was a good read as well, thanks!

Comment: Btw, are you actually building a bridge on this approach?

Comment: No, I'm building a rose arch, so it doesn't have to hold that much weight.

Comment: Wooden bridge built in 10 mins, car climb by city mayor on it  is something!